# Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio - Installed incorrectly?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image: A screenshot of the toolbar in MSSM sql]

I have just realised that my toolbar is completely doubled up, is there a setting that I need to change or do I need to do a complete uninstall? Each drop down has completely identical options.

Comment: SSMS is just Visual Studio in disguise and VS has had problems like this going back at least as far as VS2008. Have you tried going to Tools > Customize > Commands tab and clicking the Reset All button yet?

Comment: Look on the bright side - now you can get your work done twice as fast! :)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried that but no luck, I think I've just messed it up and working in reinstalling :'(